# Using of non latin characters in the Suave

Tags: f#, suave

I want to use non latin symbols in the [Suave](https://suave.io), for example, cyrillic, but getting the weird result

MCVE

```
open Suave
open Suave.Filters
open Suave.Operators
open Suave.Successful

let app =
    choose [
        GET >=>  OK "Привет, Мир!" 
    ]

startWebServer defaultConfig app
```

Result

[image]

So, the Q is - how to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For text only responses you need to set the mine type encoding: [`>=> setMimeType "text/plain; charset=utf-8"`](https://suave.io/Suave.html#dec:val%20Suave.Writers.setMimeType)

> Set the Content-Type header to the mime type given. Remember that it should include the encoding of your content. So for example, specifying a mimeType value of 'application/json; charset=utf-8' is strongly recommended (but replace 'json' with your own MIME type, of course ;))

Comment: Beat me to it: have a +1 for being speedy *and* correct. :-)

Comment: thank you, it was my first think before then post Q, but I set encoding to `1251` instead of `utf-8`, so it's not working too. Is it `utf-8` encoding not setting by default?

Comment: @FoggyFinder - The code you posed has `"Привет, Мир!"` in UTF-8 encoding, so that's what you should say your Content-Type is. Why did you use 1251?

Comment: As per the documentation Suave sends UTF-8 encoded bytes but without the content-type header the browser interprets latin-1. Might be that Suave does this because encoding can't be set without MimeType and there's no sensible default for the type.

Comment: BTW, you should **never** use a non-Unicode single-byte encodings like 1251, unless you have a specific need to do so (interop with old software). Always default to UTF-8 (with no BOM), and you'll have the fewest interop problems.

Comment: @rmunn thank you both for your help, now it is all clear to me

Comment: @CaringDev - I feel like `text/html; charset=utf-8` might be a sensible default; anyone using `text/plain` is probably only doing so during initial testing. Maybe I should suggest that in the Suave issue tracker...

Answer (score 4):

That looks like UTF-8 being interpreted as Latin-1. Try adding `>=> setMimeType "text/html; charset=utf-8"` to your app and see if that makes the browser treat your UTF-8 as actual UTF-8 instead of defaulting to the incorrect Latin-1.